# Variables and IF/ELSE statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to build an app that will alert users full name and age category from young, average, and old age but no matter which age i type in it says "You belong to young category". Please tell me what is wrong with my code. Here it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var godine = 25;
    var starost;
    if (godine < 30) {
        starost = " Vi pripadate u kategoriju mladih.";
    }
    if ((godine >= 30) && (godine < 70)) {
        starost = " Vi pripadate u kategoriju srednje starih.";
    }
    if (godine > 70) {
        starost = " Vi pripadate u kategoriju starih";
    }

    </script>
    <h1>Dobro dosli na kategorisanje starosti</h1>
    <form action="" name="frmLogin" onsubmit="alert('Korisnice: ' + ' ' + document.frmLogin.txtIme.value + ' ' + document.frmLogin.txtPrezime.value + document.frmLogin.txtStarost.value + starost)">
        Korisnicko ime: <input type="text" name="txtIme"/>
        <br>
        Korisnicko prezime: <input type="text" name="txtPrezime">
        <br>
        Godine: <input type="text" name="txtStarost">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Pokreni program">
    </form>
```

Comment: Because you set `godine = 25`. `if (godine < 30)` is always fulfilled.

Comment: Yes but if i put 75 it's still the same. I also tried with an empty variable.

Comment: Note also that you probably should be using `if else` here.  Even though it might not matter with your current logic, should someone refactor it could lead to a bug.

Comment: Tried it. Still the same... Now it says "You belong to old category" when i set the age to 55 for example when it should say "You belong to average category"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were setting `godine` value to 25 by default and **only once** when the page was loaded.

You have to catch the `godine` input with `document.getElementById` and it's value with every function call.

The function is binded with the the `button` "Pokreni program". With every click on the button, you will execute the function. The function will load new value from the `godine` input, the `starost` value will be reseted and the result will be based on it's value.

```js
function check() {

  var godine = document.getElementById('godine').value;
  var starost;
  
  if (godine < 30) {
    starost = "Vi pripadate u kategoriju mladih.";
  } else if (godine >= 30 && godine < 70) {
    starost = "Vi pripadate u kategoriju srednje starih.";
  } else if (godine > 70) {
    starost = "Vi pripadate u kategoriju starih";
  }
  console.log(starost);
}
```

```html
<h1>Dobro dosli na kategorisanje starosti</h1>
<form action="" name="frmLogin" onsubmit="alert('Korisnice: ' + ' ' + document.frmLogin.txtIme.value + ' ' + document.frmLogin.txtPrezime.value + document.frmLogin.txtStarost.value + starost)">
  Korisnicko ime: <input type="text" name="txtIme" />
  <br> Korisnicko prezime: <input type="text" name="txtPrezime">
  <br> Godine: <input type="text" name="txtStarost" id='godine'>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" onclick='check()'>Pokreni program</button>
</form>
```

If you are using only one `html` file:

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<h1>Dobro dosli na kategorisanje starosti</h1>
<form action="" name="frmLogin" onsubmit="alert('Korisnice: ' + ' ' + document.frmLogin.txtIme.value + ' ' + document.frmLogin.txtPrezime.value + document.frmLogin.txtStarost.value + starost)">
  Korisnicko ime: <input type="text" name="txtIme" />
  <br> Korisnicko prezime: <input type="text" name="txtPrezime">
  <br> Godine: <input type="text" name="txtStarost" id='godine'>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" onclick='check()'>Pokreni program</button>
</form>

<script>
function check() {

  var godine = document.getElementById('godine').value;
  var starost;
  
  if (godine < 30) {
    starost = "Vi pripadate u kategoriju mladih.";
  } else if (godine >= 30 && godine < 70) {
    starost = "Vi pripadate u kategoriju srednje starih.";
  } else if (godine > 70) {
    starost = "Vi pripadate u kategoriju starih";
  }
  console.log(starost);
  
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tnx for your help. That did it.

Comment: No problem friend ;)

Comment: @user3638147 Thank you bratko, have a great day.

Comment: But whats funny is when i copy all code that you have wrote it wont work on my computer. What could be the problem? On Run code snippet it works fine, but in my Sublime it won't

Comment: @user3638147 Show me how do you copy your all code and paste into your computer. Edit your post or make an image with your whole code.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I doesn't really matter for me, he can choose the easier way for him.

Comment: @user3638147 It still works fine for me, but seems like you have forgot about one curly brace `}` at the end of the script :)